# Newbie - matrix addition implementation in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, sum, addition

Hello i'm trying to program the addition of 2 matrices into a new one (and it does when i run the program step by step) but for some reason VS 2010 gives me an access error after it does the addition.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio>
using namespace std;

class operatii 
{
    typedef double mat[5][5];
    mat ms,m1,m2;
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;
public:
    void preg();
    int cit_val();
    void cit_mat(int&,int&,double[5][5]);
    void suma();
    void afisare(int&,int&,double[5][5]);
};

void operatii::preg()
{
cit_mat(x1,y1,m1);
cit_mat(x2,y2,m2);
suma();
afisare(x1,y1,ms);
}

int operatii::cit_val()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
return n;
}

void operatii::cit_mat(int& x,int& y,double m[5][5])
{
char r;
cout<<"Matrice patratica? Y/N ";
cin>>r;
if ((r=='y')||(r=='Y'))
{
    cout<<"Numar linii si coloane: ";
    x=cit_val();
    y=x;
}
else
{   
    cout<<"Numar linii: ";
    x=cit_val();
    cout<<"Numar coloane: ";
    y=cit_val();
}
for (int i=1;i<=x;i++)
    for (int j=1;j<=y;j++)
        cin>>m[i][j];
}

void operatii::suma()
{
if ((x1==x2)&&(y1==y2))
    for (int i=1;i<=x1;i++)
        for (int j=1;i<=y1;j++)
            ms[i][j]=m1[i][j]+m2[i][j];
else cout<<"Eroare";
}

void operatii::afisare(int& x,int& y,double m[5][5])
{ 
cout<<endl;
for (int i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
    for (int j=1;j<=y;j++)
        cout<<m[i][j];
    cout<<endl;
}
}

void main()
{
operatii matrice;
matrice.preg();
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Any kind of help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are 0-based in c++.

Change your various variants of `for (somevar=1; somevar<=something)` to `for (somevar=0; somevar<something)`

You're writing past the end of your arrays, which overwrites stack return address, leading to a return to nonexecutable code, again leading to an access violation.

Also,

```
for (int j=1;i<=y1;j++)
```

I think you want to use j not i here. Such errors are much easier to see if you use longer and more distinct variable names than "i" and "j", such as e.g. "Line" and "Column"

Comment: row and col would be more conventional